# Does anyone knows why I'm getting "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException" on my gradle converted project?

Tags: javafx, gluon-mobile

I'm trying to run converted maven based project to Gradle found on Gluon Start website (https://start.gluon.io). I configured some dependencies based on the pom.xml file:

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.9'
    id 'com.gluonhq.client-gradle-plugin' version '0.1.31'
    id 'idea'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}


mainClassName = 'com.simple.Test.Main'
dependencies {
    //implementation 'com.gluonhq:charm-glisten:5.0.2'
    //implementation 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.18'
    implementation 'com.gluonhq:connect:2.0.1'
    implementation 'org.glassfish:jakarta.json:1.1.6'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.1'
    implementation 'com.gluonhq:charm-glisten:6.0.5'
    idea.module.downloadSources = true;
    idea.module.downloadJavadoc = true;
}

javafx {
    version = '14.0.2'
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls','javafx.base','javafx.graphics']
}

gluonClient {
    // target = 'ios' // Uncomment to enable iOS
    // target = 'android' // Uncomment to enable Android
    attachConfig {
        version = "4.0.9"
        services 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage', 'keyboard', 'device'
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapplication</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>My Gluon Application</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
        <javafx.version>15</javafx.version>
        <javafx.plugin.version>0.0.4</javafx.plugin.version>
        <client.plugin.version>0.1.31</client.plugin.version>
        <charm.version>6.0.5</charm.version>
        <attach.version>4.0.8</attach.version>
        <main.class>com.mycompany.sample.Main</main.class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
            <artifactId>charm-glisten</artifactId>
            <version>${charm.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
            <artifactId>connect</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.json</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.6</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>display</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>statusbar</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>storage</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>util</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${javafx.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
                <artifactId>client-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${client.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <target>${client.target}</target>
                    <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                    <attachList>
                        <list>display</list>
                        <list>lifecycle</list>
                        <list>statusbar</list>
                        <list>storage</list>
                    </attachList>
                    <reflectionList>
                        <list>com.mycompany.sample.User</list>
                    </reflectionList>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>desktop</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <client.target>host</client.target>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
                    <artifactId>display</artifactId>
                    <version>${attach.version}</version>
                    <classifier>desktop</classifier>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle</artifactId>
                    <version>${attach.version}</version>
                    <classifier>desktop</classifier>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
                    <artifactId>storage</artifactId>
                    <version>${attach.version}</version>
                    <classifier>desktop</classifier>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>android</id>
            <properties>
                <client.target>android</client.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>ios</id>
            <properties>
                <client.target>ios</client.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>gluon-releases</id>
            <url>https://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

This is the error log:

```
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Input stream must not be null
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.image.Image.validateInputStream(Image.java:1135)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:702)
    at com.simple.Test.Main.lambda$init$1(Main.java:36)
    at com.gluonhq.impl.charm.glisten.util.CachedFactory.get(CachedFactory.java:32)
    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication.doSwitchView(MobileApplication.java:723)
    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication.switchView(MobileApplication.java:477)
    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication.switchView(MobileApplication.java:452)
    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication.continueInit(MobileApplication.java:268)
    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication.start(MobileApplication.java:232)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:277)
    ... 1 more
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalStateException: This operation is permitted on the event thread only; currentThread = JavaFX Application Thread
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.Application.checkEventThread(Application.java:441)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.Application.isNestedLoopRunning(Application.java:542)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.isNestedLoopRunning(QuantumToolkit.java:1201)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.enterNestedEventLoop(QuantumToolkit.java:637)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.application.Platform.enterNestedEventLoop(Platform.java:291)
    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.Dialog.lambda$installIntoMobileApplication$7(Dialog.java:609)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:181)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(BooleanPropertyBase.java:104)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.java:101)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:111)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase$Listener.invalidated(BooleanPropertyBase.java:239)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:348)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(BooleanPropertyBase.java:104)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:111)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:145)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty.setValue(BooleanProperty.java:81)
    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.layout.Layer.show(Layer.java:285)
    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.Dialog.showAndWait(Dialog.java:560)
    at com.gluonhq.impl.charm.glisten.util.NagScreenPresenter.lambda$showDialog$1(NagScreenPresenter.java:77)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:277)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

BUILD ABORTED

Classes:
Main.Java

```
package com.simple.Test;
import com.gluonhq.attach.display.DisplayService;
import com.gluonhq.attach.storage.StorageService;
import com.gluonhq.attach.util.Platform;
import com.gluonhq.attach.util.Services;
import com.gluonhq.attach.util.impl.ServiceFactory;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.AppBar;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.FloatingActionButton;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.mvc.View;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.visual.MaterialDesignIcon;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.visual.Swatch;
import static com.sun.javafx.PlatformUtil.isMac;
import static com.sun.javafx.PlatformUtil.isUnix;
import static com.sun.javafx.PlatformUtil.isWindows;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Optional;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Dimension2D;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
/**
 *
 * @author megaLinux
 */
public class Main extends MobileApplication {

     @Override
    public void init() {
        addViewFactory(HOME_VIEW, () -> {
            FloatingActionButton fab = new FloatingActionButton(MaterialDesignIcon.SEARCH.text,
                    e -> System.out.println("Search"));

            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(new Image(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("openduke.png")));
            imageView.setFitHeight(200);
            imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);

            Label label = new Label("Hello, Gluon Mobile!");

            VBox root = new VBox(20, imageView, label);
            root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

            View view = new View(root) {
                @Override
                protected void updateAppBar(AppBar appBar) {
                    appBar.setTitleText("Gluon Mobile");
                }
            };

            fab.showOn(view);

            return view;
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void postInit(Scene scene) {
        Swatch.LIGHT_GREEN.assignTo(scene);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(Main.class.getResource("styles.css").toExternalForm());

        if (Platform.isDesktop()) {
            Dimension2D dimension2D = DisplayService.create()
                    .map(DisplayService::getDefaultDimensions)
                    .orElse(new Dimension2D(640, 480));
            scene.getWindow().setWidth(dimension2D.getWidth());
            scene.getWindow().setHeight(dimension2D.getHeight());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(isWindows() || isMac() || isUnix()) {
            System.setProperty("javafx.platform" , "Desktop");
        }

        // define service for desktop
        StorageService storageService = new StorageService() {
            @Override
            public Optional<File> getPrivateStorage() {
                // user home app config location (linux: /home/[yourname]/.gluonmaps)
                return Optional.of(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
            }

            @Override
            public Optional<File> getPublicStorage(String subdirectory) {
                // this should work on desktop systems because home path is public
                return getPrivateStorage();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
                //noinspection ConstantConditions
                return getPrivateStorage().get().canWrite();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
                //noinspection ConstantConditions
                return getPrivateStorage().get().canRead();
            }
        };

        // define service factory for desktop
        ServiceFactory<StorageService> storageServiceFactory = new ServiceFactory<StorageService>() {

            @Override
            public Class<StorageService> getServiceType() {
                return StorageService.class;
            }

            @Override
            public Optional<StorageService> getInstance() {
                return Optional.of(storageService);
            }

        };
        // register service
        Services.registerServiceFactory(storageServiceFactory);
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

User.java

```
package com.simple.Test;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

/**
 *
 * @author megaLinux
 */
public class User {
    private StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }
}
```

Resources are located on default package:
[Resource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bstVw.png)
I don't know what do to anymore. I discarded Gluon connect first time thinking it was the cause of problem. Firstly because of glass fish (Never worked with that). Still nothing change, whether I use it or not.

Pls, help! I'm missing something?

Comment: You need to post your Main class and where you put your resources. Also you need to post the full exception. Nobody can help you without seeing what you have done and what is failing.

Comment: The error says `java.lang.NullPointerException: Input stream must not be null`, so that points to a null resource in `Main.class.getResourceAsStream("openduke.png")`. And that is due to the fact that you are looking for it under `src/resources/com/simple/Test/openduke.png`, and that doesn't exist. If you change it to `Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/openduke.png")` it will work. Alternatively, move the resource to the proper folder.

Comment: Wow! Thanks, I really appreciate it!